# Change Status Bar from Light to Dark

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, uistatusbar

In my code, I currently have a variable `dayTime` that is true if it's light outside and false if it's night. Accordingly, my code features a white scheme for day time and a dark scheme for nighttime. I need my status bar to be black if `dayTime` is true and white if `dayTime` is false. Currently, I set `override var preferredStatusBarStyle()` to return `.lightContent` but I don't know how to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` to change the status bar to black.

**EDIT:** Added Code from View Controller

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {

    var dayTime = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // gets current time to see if it is time to toggle night mode
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date as Date)
        let hour = components.hour

        if(dayTime) {
            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post some code from the controller in question? It will give more context and make answering the question much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to work. Although I had it do an async task so I could see it change after the task had completed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dayTime = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dayTime = false

        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

        if daytime {

            return .default
        }

        return .lightContent
    }
}
```